# object returning memory location instead of value

Tags: list, python-3.x, class, object

So I have this class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, length):
        self._list = length

    def get(self, index):
        try:
            return self._list[index]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

which takes in a list and returns a value, a list index I think. I am trying to get that value:

```
def my_function(a_list):
    a_list = MyClass

    for x in (10**p for p in range(1, 9)):
        if a_list:
            print(a_list)

def main():
    length = my_function(MyClass([i for i in range(0, 543)]))
```

but I keep getting only the memory location of the list, I think this is supposed to return an int.

I am hoping this is a workable bit of code, but I am struggling, with the concept of passing an "object" to a class, it doesn't make any sense to me.

Here is a test I am supposed to use:

```
def test_large_list():
    s_list = My_Class([i for i in xrange(0, 100000)])
    assert len(s_list._list) == list_length(s_list)
```

Ok, Here is my full function that works, it is done, how od I do this so that the first line takes an argument

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#def list_length(single_method_list):         This is what I am supposed to work with

from single_method_list import SingleMethodList


def my_function():      # This is how I have done it and it works.
    a_list = MyClass([i for i in range(0, 234589)])

    for x in (10**p for p in range(1, 8)):
        if a_list.get(x):
            print("More than", x)
            first = x
        else:
            print("Less than", x)
            last = x
            break

    answer = False
    while not answer:
        result = (first + last)/2
        result = int(round(result))
        print(result)
        if s_list.get(result):
            first = result
            print('first', result)
        else:
            last = result
            print('last', result)

        if s_list.get(result) and not s_list.get(result + 1):
            answer = True
            print(result + 1)


my_function()
```

I don't know what more I can give to explain where I am stuck, it is the OOP part of this that I don't know I need the same results here, just passing it to the function instead of creating it inside the function which I did in order to do the algorithm.

Comment: `MyClass` is never initialized with a list in `my_function`. Also, what's `list_length`?

Comment: Apologies, I have copied and pasted the function and forgot to change the name. This is a test I was given, and I am now trying to cover the bits I couldn't do, the actual test I have done, but as I am still struggling with the OOP part of this, this is what I am trying to understand. I have corrected the list_length to my_function. The bit in main() was my attempt to send initialize MyClass with an arbitrary list of 1 to 543.

Answer (score 0):

Well your class does something else.`MyClass` is designed to take a `List` at initialization, so the naming `length` is not a good idea.
The `get()` method of this class takes in a number and returns the element located at that particular index in the initialized `self._list`.
Your logic should be like:

```
def my_function(a_list):
    a_list = MyClass(a_list)
```

...

```
def main():
    length = my_function([i for i in range(0, 543)])
```

Comment: So my understanding is that MyClass is supposed to return a list index, the function I am writing is to work out how long the list is, so the algorithm, I have done. The bit in main, is me trying to pass that result to my_function. I will add one of the unit tests to my original post if that will help.

Comment: MyClass is a class. It will never return anything, only one if it's method.
It is a set of data with related functions. If you want to get the length of your object's list  after `a_list = MyClass(a_list)` write `print(len(a_list._list))`

Comment: So this is the point of the test, only an index is returned, but I don't know if it is an index or an int, I'm fairly certain that the actual value returned is an int. It does not return a list, or len(list) would work. I am not allowed to modify the MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify some misunderstanding that you might have.

Class does not return anything. It is a blueprint for creating objects.

What can return value is a method (function). For instance, if you want to write a method which returns length of some list:

```
def my_function(some_list):
    return len(some_list)
```

Or in your case:

```
def my_function(a_list):
    return len(a_list._list)
```

Note that you should not call your variables `list`. It's a built-in function in python which creates lists.

And as you can see there is another built-in function `len` in python which returns length of list, tuple, dictionary etc.

Hope this helps, although it's still a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I did not write the MyClass, I merely changed the name to put here, I am trying to get the int that get's returned from the method. I am not allowed to changed the method, this is a test on algorithms.

Comment: @iFunction, What method do you mean? `get` inside of MyClass?

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to find out the length of the list of which get returns an index. I just need to know how to get the integer that is returned into my function. I keep getting the memory location of MyClass, not the returned value from get method

Comment: If you need to obtain value returned by the `get` method you may try this: a_list = MyClass([...]), where `[...]` is some list. Then you just call the `get` method: `some_index = a_list.get(i)`, where `i` is any integer you can insert.

Comment: I have added my working solution to the problem that I was originally given, I just need to know how to get the value to start working with.

Comment: To clarify, I do not have a solution to this yet, I still need to know how to get the value into the function. On the part I have added, the first line in the function is my test, I need to send that line from a unit test.

Comment: is it not possible to pass a variable to a function then, am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: Why can't you pass `a_list` to `my_function` like this `my_function(a_list)` and then use `a_list` inside? By the way in my previous comment `some_index` should be `some_element`.